# How to: Inventory Rollforward in a Pivot Table

Tags: excel, dax, pivot-table

How can I create a pivot table where subtotals are shown as a running total but the rows that make up the subtotals are not? In my example below, I have set the value field to "Show Values As Running Total in Months." This gets the subtotals as I want them, but the rows in between are also shown as running totals in each activity type, which I don't want. The concept is that each subtotal should show the inventory balance at the end of each month and the rows between the subtotals should show each type of change to inventory during the month (see Desired Pivot Table below).

Example Running Total Pivot Table
[Example Running Total Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLtYo.png)

Desired Pivot Table
[Desired Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWw3l.png)